Get user subscription details using purchase token
I want to get user subscription details using purchase token, but I get an error with status 400 in google IAP APIs
This is my code
public function getPurchaseData(Request $request)
    {   
        $credentialsPath = config('services.fcm.credentials_path');
        
        if (!file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Credentials file not found'], 404);
        }
        // dd($credentialsPath);

        $fileContent = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
        $decodedCredentials = json_decode($fileContent, true);

        $client = new Client();
        
        $client->setApplicationName('AI Dating');
        // dd($client);
        $client->setAuthconfig($credentialsPath);
        // dd($client);
        $client->addScope(AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER); 
        $service = new AndroidPublisher($client);
        // dd($service);
        $packageName = config('services.google_play.package_name');
        $subscriptionId = config('services.google_play.subscription_id');
        $purchaseToken = config('services.google_play.purchase_token'); // Get purchase token from request
       
        // try {
            $result = $service->purchases_subscriptions->get($packageName,$subscriptionId,$purchaseToken);
            // dd('sdfdfdf',$result);
            $expiryTimeMillis = $result->getExpiryTimeMillis();
            $expiryDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $expiryTimeMillis / 1000);
        
            $currentDate = new \DateTime();
            $interval = $currentDate->diff($expiryDate);
            $daysRemaining = $interval->format('%a');
          return $daysRemaining;
            // echo "Days remaining: " . $daysRemaining;
        // } catch (Exception $e) {
        //     echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        // }
    }

I got error message
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid Value", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid Value", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ] } }

I want to get details of that user subscription like
expire time
remaining days
payment amount
and plan details
